# How to concatenate the correct number of duplicates into a string with for loops?

Tags: javascript, loops, duplicates

I have an array with duplicate objects, let's say: [A, A, B, C]. With for loops I concat the names of duplicates into a string. I tried this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myArray.data.length - 1; i ++) {
  for (var j = i + 1; j < myArray.data.length; j ++) {
    if (myArray.data[i].id == myArray.data[j].id) {
      identicalObjects = identicalObjects + myArray.data[i].name + ", " + myArray.data[j].name;
    }
  }
}
```

This prints: "A, A", which is correct. However, if the array is [A, A, A, B, C], it prints "A, A, A, A, A, A" which is not correct, there are only 3 duplicates not 6. I cannot just cut the string, because there are some cases when different objects (with different id's) are returned as duplicates, and I need to know their names to know which ones exactly they are.

One solution that comes to my mind is storing names in an array, and if the amount of the same name is greater than 2, cut the amount of the others in half, then convert to a string. Is there anything more simple and efficient though?

Comment: You're adding `myArray.data[i].name` twice, try `identicalObjects += (identicalObjects ? ", " : "") + myArray.data[i].name`

Answer (score 0):

> However, if the array is [A, A, A, B, C], it prints "A, A, A, A, A, A"

This is because when i = 0 and j = 1, you get a match, and identicalObjects is set to "A, A".  You get another match when i = 0 and j = 2 and set identicalObjects to its previous value plus "A, A".  Then you get another match when i = 1 and j = 2 and perform the same concatenation.

Why not use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object and use the object as the key, with the value being the count?

Comment: That is not true because the second iteration starts from `i + 1`, the OP's approach will start failing only after there are 4 or more duplicates. Here is a test https://jsbin.com/gaxelenowe/edit?js,console

Comment: My point was not that the algorithm finds 3 matches, it was that it printed "A, A" for each match found.  So when there are 3 matches, you get 3 * "A, A".

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most straightforward way to implement this, but I think it should get the job done.

```
var uniqueLetters = myArray.filter(distinct);

for(var i = 0; i < uniqueLetters.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < myArray.Length; j++){

        if(myArray.data[j] == uniqueLetters[i]){
            identicalObjects = identicalObjects + myArray.data[i].name + ", " + myArray.data[j].name;
        }
    }
}
```

So, for example. Let's say you have an array [A, A, B, C]. `uniqueLetters` will contain [A, B, C]. then looping through your original array, you check against the distinct array.

Again, this probably isn't the most straightforward way to handle this, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

It is more easy and flexible if you convert your array of objects to List. 
List is more powerful and you can do lot more things with the list.

In your example, you are trying to find duplicates based on ids. With list this can be achieved in single sentence.

```
Map<Integer, List<YourObject>> yourObjectMap = empArray.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(YourObject::getId));
```